# Integers divisible by 4 but not by 3 and 16

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

For $n \leq 1000$ I am interested in the integers who are divisible by 4 but **not** by 3 and 16. Say $a_i$ is the property that an integer is divisible by $i$. Inclusion-Exclusion gives us:
\begin{align}
N(a_{3}'a_{4}a_{16}') = N - N(a_3) - N(a_4') - N(a_{16}) + N(a_3a_4') + N(a_3a_{16}) + N(a_4'a_{16}) - N(a_{3}'a_{4}a_{16}') 
\end{align}
I can determine those first 4 terms correctly:

• N = 1000

• $N(a_3)= \lfloor \frac{1000}{3} \rfloor = 333$

• $N(a_4')= 1000 - \lfloor \frac{1000}{4} \rfloor = 750 $

• $N(a_{16})= \lfloor \frac{1000}{16} \rfloor = 62$

Now it is becoming harder to working things out. We can say for $N(a_3a_4')$ that those are all the numbers that are divisible by 3 but not by 4. We can again apply inclusion-exlusion on this term but it don't seem to help. How can I work this out?

Comment: How can an integer be divisible by 16 but not by 4?

Comment: It's going to take a while to find an integer divisible by $\;16\;$ but *not* by $\;4\;$ ...

Comment: A divisor of a divisor is a divisor.

Comment: Sorry there is some mistake in the question. I will edit.

Comment: There is a joke here. There are formulae which work if the numbers are  relatively prime in some appropriate sense. You can plug the numbers in every time, but the precondition counts.

Comment: @Timbuc Just for fun, is infinity divisible by every integer, by none ... ??

Comment: @MarkBennet Well, just for fun: tell me first *what* is infinity and whether it is odd or even...:)

Comment: You mean "divisible by 4, but not by both 3 and 16"?

Comment: @Timbuc The infinity I believe in is divisible by 16 - is it divisible by 4? I once - in a completely different forest (not even a different part of the same forest) was given a test in law for which all the answers were "trivially impossible" and which I, and most of the class, failed. Questions to make you think and understand, Great teaching. Embarrassed students, who would never make the same mistake again.

Comment: @MarkBennet Well, when I'll believe in some infinity then I'll be able, perhaps, to respond you. In the meantime I accept infinity as a definite point  in some contexts (compactification, elliptic curves with projective geometry, etc.) , *very* different from  usual numbers and thus with no parallel notion of "divisibility".

Comment: @Timbuc Glorious answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$250$ numbers are divisible by $4$. Now use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

$$250-\left\lfloor\frac{250}{3}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{250}{4}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{250}{3\times4}\right\rfloor=125$$

Please note that we use $4$ instead of $16$, because those $250$ numbers are not consecutive - they already contain only multiples of $4$, so we need to exclude only those that are multiples of yet "another $4$" (the credit for this fix goes to @AndréNicolas, as implied in the comment below).

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I agree, this answer is wrong. I will fix it or delete. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: confirmed by awk 'BEGIN{for(i=4; i<=1000; i+=4){if (i%3!=0&&i%16!=0) {print i}}}' | wc -l